# SolrJ how to get data from binary field

Tags: solr, solrj

I have data (small picture) in binary format in Solr 6, when using SolrJ library I got in the response reference like this `[B@157dac6d` but not the base64 string from Solr. Any idea how to extract the data back?

Example png:

```
"preview_db":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...ABJRU5ErkJggg"
```

Comment: Are you sure the base64 data as actually been indexed to Solr? Do you see the data if you retrieve it with `*:*` in the admin interface? The [B@..] syntax is usually serialized form of a class somewhere in the processing chain (i.e. a database field or something similar)

Comment: yes I am sure, the code `preview_db:...` is copied from the admin UI

Comment: What is the field type and what does your code using SolrJ look like?

Comment: field type:solr.BinaryField, SolrJ returns as a byte array ( class [B )...so ouky,I need to decode it...

Comment: Ouk I solved it (on your advice focusing on the bytes there) ... 

                byte[] bytes = (byte[]) filedValue;
                byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
                String s = new String(endcoded);
                System.out.println(s);

Comment: Post it as an answer and accept it yourself

Answer (score 1):

SolrJ returns the solr.BinaryField as byte[] array (`class [B`).
So to get the binary as a base64 String again we need to cast the response value, encode the byte array and then create String.

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) filedValue;
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
String s = new String(endcoded);
System.out.println(s);
```